# My task is to print the friends of my friends, that are not my friends

Tags: java

```
public void notMyFriend(Student student1) {
        System.out.println("Friends who are not my friends:");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < student1.friendList.size();i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < friendList.size(); j++) {
                if (student1.friendList.get(i) == friendList.get(j)) continue;
                else {
                    System.out.println(student1.friendList.get(i).getName());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

That code fragment does print my friends and the friends of my friends that are mutual for us,not the friends that are not mutual.I cant understand why? Do someone can help me?

Student:

```
public class Student { 
    private int Number; 
    private String Name; 
    private String Gender; 
    private List<Student> friendList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }
```

Comment: Please, attach the Student class also

Comment: What is `friendList`?

Comment: "*[...] that are mutual for us two times in a row.*" - What does that mean? --- A comment on your code: even if possible, you should never leglect optional braces around `if`, `else`, ... and always make a newline behind an opening brace.

Comment: public  class Student {
    private int Number;
    private String Name;
    private String Gender;
    private List<Student> friendList = new ArrayList<Student>();

Comment: What @markspace is saying: please [edit] your question and include this information in your original question.

Comment: Set operations: "friends of my friends" [`addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-); "not my friends" [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Student class has a fitting implementation of `equals()`, you can use [`removeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

```
hisFriends.removeAll(yourFriends);
System.out.println(hisFriends); // not your friends
```

Comment: @VikoManafov If an answer solves your problem don't forget to accept! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

To print friends that are not mutual without using set operations:

```
 public void notMyFriend(Student student1) {
    System.out.println("Friends who are not my friends:");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < student1.friendList.size();i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < friendList.size(); j++) 
            if (student1.friendList.get(i) == friendList.get(j)) break;

            if(j==friendList.size())
             System.out.println(student1.friendList.get(i).getName());

         }
}
```